# C++ How to print the smallest number from an array of size n without using sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, primes

I have to WAP to print the smallest & largest prime no of a array of given size without sorting . I have written the code for largest number but for smallest number it doesn't run because i am comparing the value of a prime number with min which is initialised 0 , but if i break the If_else in two parts

1. containg c==2 check
2. containg a[i]

then it runs because then in c==2 , min has been supplied with a value from the array but if i run them together they dont
so any work around here to get me smallest number without breaking the if_else . 
the code is follow

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main ()
{
  int i,j,m;
  clrscr();
  int a[20],x,min=0,c=0;
  cout<<"Enter size of array "<<endl;
  cin>>m;
  cout<<"Enter "<<m<<" Numbers "<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    cin>>a[i];
  }
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    for(j=1;j<=a[i];j++)
    {
      if(a[i]%j==0)
      {
        c++;
      }
    }
    if(c==2 && a[i]<min)//problem is here 
    {
      min=a[i];
    }
    c=0;
  }
  cout<<endl<<"the min prime no out of array is " <<min;
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Initialize `min` with `INT_MAX` then the check to find min will work...

Comment: Or with any element of the array.

Comment: @Nim how do you suggest doing that ? 
can't do it with any other element because only prime no have to be checked

Comment: If you're trying to find the min and max, why is there no `min` variable? @SanchitBansal you have `if(c==2 && a[i]>max){max=a[i];}`... initializa a `min` as suggested and add `if(c==2 && a[i]<min){min=a[i];}`. Further, move your prime-checking code to its own function such as `isPrime(int);`, returning 0 for not prime, 1 for prime.... then `if (isPrime(a[i])) { if (a[i]>max)...;   if (a[i]<min)...; }`

Comment: @mah i did that , but it doesnt work now it only gives output 0 . because it is comparing the prime no with zero and so zero wins all the time . if i initialise min=10000 and then run the code . it will be fine , but thats no how you are supposed to do

Comment: @SanchitBansal you should initialize it to `INT_MAX` as Nim suggested. This is the largest integer the computer can hold. Initializing it with any element in the array is generally ok but in your case it isn't, you would have to initialize it to any prime number in the array instead. As to "not how you are supposed to do it" -- you've presented a problem but you've not presented rules about how to solve that problem. If there are specific rules (beyond not sorting), you need to present them in full.

Comment: I don't understand why it has been downvoted (twice). He has tried something on his own, posted his code and now asking for the logical error and responding to the comments the way he understands them. I think this is what this forum is for. So upvoting...

Comment: Strongly agreed with @Vikram.exe Upvoted

Comment: indentation should be fixed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split your problem:

- Filter prime number
- then find_min_max

For min_max, you may use something like this:

```
void find_min_max(const std::vector<int>& primes, int& minValue, int& maxValue)
{
    assert(!primes.empty());

    auto result = std::minmax_element(primes.begin(), primes.end());
    minValue = *result.first;
    maxValue = *result.second;
}
```

Comment: If you have already filtered the collection to contain only the primes, then you could just use `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` to do the hard work for you. That said, your system finds the min and max at the same time, meaning only one loop through the code.

Comment: @Jarod42 now +1 :-) BTW, I coded up something myself to also show how the first step is done. See my answer below.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s5B46aHM
how is this ? by storing in 2nd array and then comparing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are starting with the programming stuff and haven't read about complexities and function calls, so putting it in a simple way that a beginner can understand it.

take a variable to check if a prime number is present or not

`int foundPrime = 0;`   // Use boolean here if you are comfortable

Since you want to find both max and min, change this part:

```
if(c==2 && a[i]>max)//problem is here 
{
    max=a[i];
}
```

TO:

```
if (c == 2)
{
    if (foundPrime == 0)
    {
        foundPrime = 1;
        max = a[i];
        min = a[i];
    }
    else
    {
        if (a[i] < min)
            min = a[i];

        if (a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];
    }
}
```

And change the final print statement:

```
cout<<endl<<"the min prime no out of array is " <<min;
```

to something like:

```
if (foundPrime == 1)
{
cout<<endl<<"the min prime no out of array is " <<min;
cout<<endl<<"the max prime no out of array is " <<max;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"No prime numbers found in the array."
}
```

Comment: Sir 
i thought of an another way, by storing the prime numbers in another array and then initializing minimum value as b[0] and then comparing . see this code and tell how it is because it tells you when there are no prime numbers too just like your code . only a little shorter (no offence meant) and i will wait for your reply , make improvements 
if possible sir 
http://pastebin.com/s5B46aHM

Answer (score 0):

Here is a worked example that defines an `is_prime` predicate, then uses `boost::filter_iterator` and `std::minmax_element` to get the smallest and largest prime from an unsorted range in **one pass over the data**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

struct is_prime
{
    bool operator()(int n) const
    {
        int small_primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };
        return std::all_of(std::begin(small_primes), std::end(small_primes), [=](int const& p) {
            return n == p || n % p != 0;
        });
    }    
};

int main() 
{
    int numbers[] = { 24, 12, 7, 8, 11, 95, 47 };
    auto pb = boost::make_filter_iterator(is_prime{}, std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
    auto pe = boost::make_filter_iterator(is_prime{}, std::end(numbers), std::end(numbers));

    auto result = std::minmax_element(pb, pe);
    if (result != std::make_pair(pb, pb))
        std::cout << *(result.first.base()) << " " << *(result.second.base());
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff3fb319239cc9e3).

Comment: You may check if iterators in result are "valid" (empty case).

Comment: @Jarod42 tnx, good point. Updated the answer by checking the resulting iterator pair against `std::make_pair(pb, pb)`, which is what `std::minmax_element` returns in case there are no primes in the input.